# In a state lottery four digits are drawn at random one at a time with replacement from 0 to 9...

Tags: probability

So I'm studying a bit for an exam and I'm a little confused on part of this problem.  The problem is as follows.

> In a state lottery four digits are drawn at random one at a time with
>   replacement from 0 to 9. Suppose that you win if any permutation of
>   your selected integers is drawn. Give the probability of winning if
>   you select:
>
> a. 6,7,8,9 b. 6,7,8,8, c. 7,7,8,8 d. 7,8,8,8

Now I understand part a well enough - if you have 4 numbers, you can arrange them 24 different ways (you can put the first number in one of 4 spots, the second in one of 3, the third in one of two, etc. etc.) and since you have 10 numbers and are picking them and then putting them back and picking again, you have a total of 10^4 possible combinations of numbers to get.

My main issue comes with part b, where you have two of the same number - you still have the same number of total outcomes, but I've run into the issue where I don't really understand how to deal with "arranging" the numbers because two of them are the same...

Could someone break this down for me?

Answer (score 1):

After staring at the book explanation for a while, I think I actually understand it now - essentially what this is is a distinguishable permutation.

You take the 4 numbers you have, and since two of them are unique, and there are two that are indistinguishable, you want to take the total number of position combinations you have - $n!$ (in my case it would be $4!$) and then you want to select" "r" out of "n" positions for the indistinguishable numbers, then you want to place them, and then place the remaining indistinguishable numbers - So I would be left with $\frac{4!}{1!1!2!}$ actual combinations (because you can arrange the "8"s in two ways, and then that only leaves you with 1 spot for the 6 and one for the 7)

Then you simply divide that by the total number of possible combinations (10000) and you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Total number of possible outcomes $=10^4$

**Case 1:** Select  $6,7,8,9$
Favorable outcomes $=4^4$
probability $=\dfrac{4^4}{10^4}$

**Case 2:** Select  $6,7,8,8$
Favorable outcomes $=3^4$
probability $=\dfrac{3^4}{10^4}$

**Case 3:** Select  $7,7,8,8$
Favorable outcomes $=2^4$
probability $=\dfrac{2^4}{10^4}$

**Case 4:** Select  $7,8,8,8$
Favorable outcomes $=2^4$
probability $=\dfrac{2^4}{10^4}$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.   The answer for case 2 is $\frac{1}{10^4} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!$ since there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the positions of the $8$s and the remaining numbers can be arranged in $2!$ ways.